# Edubuntu video playback and apt-get

Tags: ubuntu

They had installed some modified [Edubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edubuntu)'s at school.

So I have some questions about setting some things up:

1. How can we play HD videos? They are made for Windows machines and are in WMV format but we need to play them in our multimedia class but I don't know how - which player, which codecs, etc.
2. How to properly edit the `/etc/apt/sources` file? Anything we try to install via apt-get it just says that E:\ is not available. Which repositories should be put in there so we could be able to install some tools?
3. Where are viruses/trojans usually put in Ubuntu? I mean in which directories? Because our computers are behaving really slow and we need to check for malware manually - we are not even allowed to install any kind of anti-virus software. What are the usual directories and places for hiding such files, how are they hiddem, how to recognize them, etc.?
4. Any others nice tricks/tips that we need to know.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Super User. I recommend you to separate your several questions into individual, well, questions. That way, it will be easier to get answer for each of these individual ones. Keep in mind that this site is not a forum, and as such, doesn't work like one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK:

1. You will need to install some codecs using - sorry! - `apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-* ffmpeg`. I use the [Arista Transcoder](http://programmer-art.org/projects/arista-transcoder) app to convert videos on Ubuntu, and it works quite well. The only problem is that you may have to install some codecs - . If you can't do that, you'll need to use a video converter on Windows, or perhaps try downloading [MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) or [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) separately, and converting with them.

   I would suggest converting to Ogg Theora if the converter program supports it.
2. The GUI way: `System->Administration->Software Sources`. The CLI way:

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   Substitute nano for your favourite console editor - nano is by far the easiest if you aren't familiar with console editors, though.
3. Viruses and malware are practically a non-issue on Linux systems. There are many different places it could hide. If you do have a virus problem (unlikely, IMHO), realistically you will need a virus scanning app. (Here's a [review](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/get-best-virus-scanner-linux) of Linux anti-virus programs from a recent Linux Format.)

Answer (score 0):

For the codecs, you could try the "Ubuntu Restricted Extras" package in your package manager. For the sources, `E:\` is a Windows filepath, *nix uses filepaths starting with / as root, and partitions/drives are mounted under /mnt or /mount, generally.

There are very few viruses/trojans for *nix, and even if there were, there wouldn't be "standard" directories to hide them any more than there is on windows - if they were easy to find they'd be very bad viruses :)

As for the 4th option, your questions make me think you're thinking about ubuntu like it's windows. You should stop doing that, it isn't - it does many things very differently. Forget everything you know about windows, because most likely it isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As for #3: what are the specs on the computers?

For #4: If you don't have sudo access, then you can't install codecs or software through the package manager.

You can compile and run programs in your local user account, but I think the only language installed by default is Python.